# Break Line between Angular Tabs

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have Four tabs tab1,tab2,tab3 and tab4

below is my html code of tabs

```
    <tabset>
<tab heading="Tab1" [active]="defaultTab==16 ? true : false" >
<ng-template #tab1Comp></ng-template>
</tab>

<tab heading="Tab2" [active]="defaultTab==18 ? true : false" >
<ng-template #tab2Comp></ng-template>
</tab>
   <tab heading="Tab3" [active]="defaultTab==19 ? true : false" id="restart">
<ng-template #tab3Comp></ng-template>
</tab>

<tab heading="Tab4" [active]="defaultTab==17 ? true : false" >
<ng-template #tab4Comp></ng-template>
</tab>
    </tabset>
```

for above code tabs are coming in single row like below

```
Tab1 Tab2 Tab3 Tab4
```

I want output shoud be like below into two rows

```
Tab1 Tab2

Tab3 Tab4
```

I have applied css tab3 also but break line not working

```
#restart:before {
content: ' ';
clear: right;
display: block;

 }
```

But above css is not applying to tab3 to break line and i dont want two tabset.

i need correctly css which will be Easly apply to my tabs.

Comment: Are those `tabset` and `tab` elements provided by bootstrap or some other third party thing? Anyway an easy option would be using flex wrapping `tabset {display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}` with children at 50% flex-basis `tabset tab {flex: 50%}` but I'm not sure if you're ok with equal sizing so left as comment.

Comment: this is boostrap tabs import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs' . @ChrisW.

Comment: is there any way to do like above my question by mentioning id like restart to break line. @ChrisW.

Comment: i have added flex wrapping is not applying to me. @ChrisW.